# Solve Max Velocity given Distance, Time, Initial velocity, Acceleration, Deceleration

Tags: physics

For a motor application I wan't to be able to find the maximum velocity I should ask my motor to use knowing:

- Distance to go **D**
- Time to travel **T**
- Acceleration **a**
- Deceleration **d**
- Initial velocity **v0**

So that my motor will go from initial position **p0** with initial velocity **p0** to final position with velocity = 0.

I found several post doing it the other way. Solving for time given maximum velocity. And I have a hard time reversing the equation.

Thank you for your help.

Ben

Comment: Can you write down the solution for time given maximum velocity? If possible, do it by editing your post and using MathJax. The link for reference is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vehicle accelerates from velocity $v_0$ to velocity $v_{max}$ over a time $T_1$, then we have

$T_1 = \frac{v_{max} -v_0}{a}$

If it then decelerates from velocity $v_{max}$ to rest over a time $T_2$, then we have

$T_2 = \frac{v_{max}}{d}$

We know that the total time $T$ must equal $T_1+T_2$, so

$T = \frac{v_{max} -v_0}{a} + \frac{v_{max}}{d}$

Re-arranging this to solve for $v_{max}$ gives:

$v_{max} = \frac{d}{a+d}(aT+v_0)$

Comment: Thank you for your help!